# Sourcetree Git - Checkout file disable modifying

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-checkout

Before Sourcetree I was using Wincvs and it had one nice feature which I cannot find in Sourcetree.

I am trying to set it up in that way where first i have to checkout a file before I can modify it (so the file is just readable before checkout). Then it would also be fine that everyone who wants to edit this file gets a notification that somebody else(with the actual name) is editing this file.

Now (with Sourcetree) it is just like I am editing files in me IDE and I see the changed files in Sourcetree (where I can commit and push), but there is no checking if somebody else is modifying the same files.

And one more question, is it somehow possible to retreive just the changed files ? When I pull from the server Sourcetreee tries to merge changed files, but I want them fresh from the server (without merging). I have seen that it is possible in that way that the project is being "deleted" and pulled from the server, but I want the changed file to overwrite my local ones.

Thanks for any info

Comment: as git is by nature decentralized, I think it would be impossible to notify people you are working on a specific file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locking a file is simply not possible with Git, because Git is distributed and not central, unlike CVS or Subversion (this has nothing to do with SourceTree, since SourceTree is just a Git client). The check, if someone else has also changed a file (or more specifically, the tree) will be done when you push your commits. When another developer pushed another commit, your push is rejected and you have to fetch and merge the commits from the other developer (btw., you should read a bit more about Git basics).

If you want to overwrite local files, then you can just fetch the branch, and the reset your local branch to the remote branch (git reset --hard will overwrite all your local changes).

Comment: Yes, it seems like it is really not possible with git(found some other topic on SO). I think I just need time to get used to it, since in wincvs things where "more" organized. Right now I am working on 2 different working stations on the same project (as my first project with git). And i always want to keep them in sync (when i change something on one station i push it and work later on the other station). Now i often get a conflict when trying to pull from server and thats annoying (then i delete a file and pull again). Thanks

Comment: That shouldn't happen, if you're the only one working with this repository. You should check, if you have some auto-generated files in the Git repository, which could cause these conflicts. If so, it would be better to remove them from the repository and add them to the .gitignore file.

Comment: that was the issue in first place, but then i set all the .class files (and some other extensions which i found out are auto-generated) to the ignore list but still getting the error for an xml file (it's an Android application and I got the error with Manifest.xml). But I will keep an eye on that, and as I said I need some time to get used to the different concept of git (in compare with Wincvs)